# Erro Waiting for table level lock MySQL aplicação Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Tenho um aplicação Java swing que utiliza o banco de dados MySQL, em sua operação depois de passado algum tempo em funcionamento percebi que a aplicação travava em alguns momentos, sendo necessário reiniciar o computador para conseguir realizar o processo novamente pois mesmo fechando a aplicação e a abrindo novamente o mesmo problema persistia. Consegui identificar que o problema ocasionava no momento de realizar a gravação ou atualização de informações. Consultando o Workbench chequei as conexões e vi que havia um usuário parado com o comando referente ao processo.
O estado daquela conexão estava como `Waiting for table level lock` agora não tenho a certeza de que é ela que esta causando o problema ou algo da minha aplicação que não esta tratando de forma correta.

DAO.java

```
 public int create(Produto produto) {
    EntityManager em = null;
    try {
        em = getEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(produto);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } finally {
        if (em != null) {
            em.close();
        }
    }

    return produto.getCodproduto();
}

public void edit(Produto produto) throws NonexistentEntityException, Exception {
    EntityManager em = null;
    try {
        em = getEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        produto = em.merge(produto);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        String msg = ex.getLocalizedMessage();
        if (msg == null || msg.length() == 0) {
            Integer id = produto.getCodproduto();
            if (findProduto(id) == null) {
                throw new NonexistentEntityException("The produto with id " + id + " no longer exists.");
            }
        }
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        if (em != null) {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Você está fazendo commit e fechando a transação corretamente?

Comment: vou atualizar a questão adicionando o código que me solicitou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Junto a aplicação também funciona uma aplicação de backup que projetada pela equipe, e com o banco de dados de um tamanho maior, o tempo para realizar o backup aumenta, ocasionando o aguardo da finalização do backup para realizar a gravação dos dados no banco. A principio fiz a remoção da aplicação de backup e estou analisando um forma mais eficaz e independente de fazer o backup sem causar problemas no desempenho da aplicação.